# Calculation to be made while updating a field

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
Origin     Dest      Date                              Amount    50% Due
92509      0021      2013-07-30 00:00:00.000           5.37       0.00
92509      0021      2013-07-30 00:00:00.000           5.37       0.00
92509      0021      2013-07-30 00:00:00.000           5.37       0.00
92509      0021      2013-07-31 00:00:00.000           5.37       2.69
92509      0021      2013-07-31 00:00:00.000           5.37       2.69
92509      0021      2013-07-31 00:00:00.000           5.37       2.69
92509      0021      2013-08-01 00:00:00.000           5.37       2.69
92509      0021      2013-08-01 00:00:00.000           5.37       2.69
42101      0029      2013-03-06 00:00:00.000           6.06       0.00
42101      0029      2013-03-06 00:00:00.000           6.06       0.00
42101      0029      2013-03-07 00:00:00.000           6.06       3.03
42101      0029      2013-03-07 00:00:00.000           6.06       3.03                        
42101      0030      2013-03-06 00:00:00.000           6.06       0.00   
42101      0030      2013-03-06 00:00:00.000           6.06       0.00   
42101      0030      2013-03-07 00:00:00.000           6.06       3.03   
42101      0030      2013-03-07 00:00:00.000           6.06       3.03
```

So I have a table something similar to what i shown above. Right now, the 50% Due field is empty. I need to fill that field with values as shown above.

The 50% due field should populate values that are half of what is present in the Amount field. But, it should fill zero for the initial date (2013-07-30 00:00:00.000) and for the consecutive days it should fill half of what is present in the Amount field.

I have a lot of rows like these that needs to get updated. Also there are rows with different Origin and Destination.

I am dealing with some freight parcels. The data describes the parcels that were sent to the same destination from same origin on consecutive days. The parcels that were sent on consecutive days could have been sent together on the initial date itself. So I am trying to generate a claim for those parcels that were sent on consecutive days to the same destination from the same origin. And the 50% Due would be the claim!

I am fairly new to SQL! This seems to be very complicated for me. Please help.

Comment: you'd probably have to do it in 3 queries. one `select` to fetch the value of that "first" date, and then 2 `update`: one to zero-out the field where the dates match, and another to do the 50% calculation.

Comment: Thanks i am trying something on lines what you have told. But I would really appreciate a query!

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out what you are trying to do. Why do you have so many duplicates in your table? Are you wanting the first 50% to be added to the first date after the original date and the second 50% to the next date? Or is it always 50% after the first date? Your data looks like it is in serious need of normalization.

Comment: Hi Sean Lange, it always 50% after the first date! And this is exactly how my data looks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I guess there is something you haven't told us. On the sample data Origin and Dest is the same for all rows. What shoud be the result with other values, please edit your post to include more data, so we can guess what you really want. I agree with Sean, your data needs normalization.

Comment: Updated please check now!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update all origin/dest combinations that had an entry on the prior day then you can do this:

```
update t
set [50% due]=coalesce(cast(p.amount/2.0 as smallmoney),0.00)
from [table] t
left join [table] p
    on t.origin=p.origin and t.dest=p.dest 
    and dateadd(D,-1,cast(t.[date] as date))=cast(p.[date] as date)
```

or use a cte and LAG in SQL 2012 and later versions:

```
;with previous as
(
    select origin,dest,[date]
    ,LAG(cast([date] as date),1,cast([date] as date)) OVER (PARTITION BY origin,dest ORDER BY cast([date] as date)) as previous
    from (select distinct origin, dest, [date]
            from [table]) a
)
update t
set [50% Due]=case when dateadd(D,-1,cast(t.[date] as date))<>cte.previous then 0.00 else cast(t.[amount]/2.0 as smallmoney) end
from [table] t
join previous cte
    on cte.origin=t.origin and cte.dest=t.dest and cte.[date]=t.[date]
```

If you want to update all your records based on the earliest day that the origin/dest combination occurred, then this will work in SQL Server:

```
;with earliest as
(
    select origin,dest,min(cast([date] as date)) earliest
    from [table]
    group by origin,dest
)
update t
set [50% Due]=case when cast(t.[date] as date)=cte.earliest then 0.00 else cast(t.[amount]/2.0 as smallmoney) end
from [table] t
join earliest cte
    on cte.origin=t.origin and cte.dest=t.dest
```

If you want to update all your records only based on the earliest day in the table and you don't care about the orgin/dest combination then you don't need the cte to group the earliest dates and you can simply do the compare in the update.

```
UPDATE t
set [50% Due]=case when cast(t.[date] as date)=(select min(cast(t.date as date))) then 0.00 else cast(t.[amount]/2.0 as smallmoney) end
```

Comment: Hi Ben Kean..Your query helped me to fill out few columns as required but it failed to do so for different Ship Origin and Dest combination with same dates. You can understand what I am trying to say if you take a look at the last 8 data lines in the question I have posted. According to your query, values in the 50%Due field for the last 4 rows are getting filled as 3.03. But I need them to be filled as shown in the question above. Kindly help. It would be much appreciated. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Maash If the last 4 rows are getting filled as 3.03 then there has to be an instance of that origin/destination combination prior to those dates.  Try adding `order by t.origin,t.dest,t.date` and you will see what I mean.  I have added a solution that doesn't group by origin and dest to determine the min date.

Comment: @Maash I see you changed the question to specify that it it has to only divide amount by 2 if there are consecutive days preceeding the date.  If you are using SQL 2012 or later you can do this with LAG.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: And finally I thought of a simple way to do it with a left join.